# How do we not think everyone is the same person from a slightly different position?

Tags: recognition

When we meet someone and say they have a beard. When we meet another person with a beard. How do we know that is not the same person?

On the other hand, when we see the same person from a slightly different angle we recognise them.

So how do we not over-fit or under-fit on facial recognition?

Is it just practice?

If we just lived on an island with people who looked very different from each other (e.g. the old one, the tall one, the fat one, the bald one, the young one) and then travelled to a country with lots of similar looking people. Would we think they all looked the same?

Comment: Your question was put on hold. I think it does hold potential but it is rather broad. Especially the last sentences make the question kind of vague. For example, I think a better-focused question would be *How does the visual system account for variations in facial features when the viewing angle is changed slightly?*